# Who is Sasakura's father?

Tags: bartender

In the manga, *Bartender*, there have been a couple of oblique references to Sasakura Ryu's father being well known. Who is he?

Comment: I don't think we've ever been given a name, but people refer to him as "The Master" for his amazing ability to mix drinks. According to Sasakura Ryu's grandfather, he died sometime after World War II.

Comment: @JonLin At one point, I was expecting Bartender to move along the lines of Oishinbo. I guess we still have 11 volumes to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a flashback that starts in Glass 113, "The Past", it is revealed that his father is named "Sasakura Genichi" who was a former Diet member. His nickname was "The Monster of Nagata."